# Shutdown after a certain time

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I am done using my laptop but I am using the hotspot in my smart phone. So I want my laptop to be awake for next one hour. How can I Shutdown the laptop after one hour of time?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

### Scheduling a shutdown

To shutdown run the command:

```
sudo shutdown -P +60
```

That will wait 60 mins before starting the shutdown sequence.

You could do:

```
sudo shutdown -P 1:00
```

to shutdown at 1 AM and

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

to shutdown now.

A message is broadcast to all terminals to warn about the shutdown.

### Cancel a pending shutdown

After, starting a shutdown, if the time argument is **not** "+0" or "now", you can use:

```
sudo shutdown -c
```

to cancel the scheduled shutdown.

Comment: is there any way to exit the shutdown program. When I press `ctrl + c` after executing shutdown, it also aborts the scheduled shutdown.

Comment: Just press Ctrl+Z, which will allow any command to run in the background

Comment: what is mean  by -p?

Comment: @PrashantTapase power off fully

Comment: Does this command override any programs that might be running at the time?

Comment: @Josh I believe so.

Comment: is there anywhere a pretty gui? maybe qshutdown ?