# Is there a way to automatically turn off the computer at a certain time of the day?

Tags: shutdown, schedule

For a long a long time its been a problem for me (the human) to go to sleep early. A part of the problem is definitely that I often been to long by the computer at night I mess up my day rhythm and my life.

How can I solve this I would love to tell my computer to turn of at a certain time of the day? And give me a count down and be able to turn on again if I really need to turn it on afterwards and then be put to sleep again. Is there a thing like that?

[I found this](http://www.timteatro.net/2011/01/16/sleep-timer-suspend-script-for-linux/) but I don't know how to implement it. I'm a bit noob at Linux.

Comment: Yes, there are programs for that, but  there is also scripting way. If this is a desktop with GUI, one can use dbus , and cron to schedue a shutdown. Would you be interested in something like this ?

Comment: This isn't a full solution, but take a look at this Q: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505929/shutdown-after-a-certain-time

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way would be through the command line:

try `sudo shutdown -P 60` to shut down the machine in 60 minutes.

Alternatively you could set a time to shut down, using 24h format. For example `sudo shutdown -P 1:00` will shut down the machine at 1:00 AM in the morning.

`sudo shutdown -P now` will shut down the CPU right away, e.g. now.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks the 
sudo shutdown -P 1:00
did the trick.  
Is there a way that it can come on everyday automatically?

Comment: You can most likely script it if you have some experience. Maybe this helps you: https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/linux/ubuntu-15-04-startup-shutdown-script-systemd/

Comment: I tried to make the script.. but it failed.  I get this message (maybe I should make a new thread?):


(gedit:2971): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Looks like an error with the dbus or the service. However I have to admit I lack the skills to help you there any further. It might be a good idea indeed to mark this question as answered and post the script one in a new question so it's easier to find. Remember to post your error as well. Should get an answer today. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This also works: with the -h option:

```
sudo shutdown -h 17:00 "Shutting down my Linux."
```

Here is the output:

```
Broadcast message from maestro@maestro-5567
    (/dev/pts/10) at 15:28 ...

The system is going down for halt in 92 minutes!
Shutting down my Linux.
```