# Is there a timer command in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want to know if there is a command X that allows me to execute another command Y after a certain time. I would specify the time in X. The idea comes from a sleep timer, where I found:
[Shutdown after a certain time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505929/shutdown-after-a-certain-time)

With:

```
sudo shutdown -P +60
```

But say I want to do as described above:

```
command X -time 60 ls -a
```

Is there something like this and if not could I add it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run it like this:

```
sleep 60 && ls -a
```

But that blocks your shell until the wait is over.

To avoid the blocked terminal, group the commands:

```
{sleep 60 && ls -a ; } &
```

Be aware that the commands in braces are then executed in a subshell, e.g. variables defined there will not be available in the main shell.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I ll test it later.